# Testing output twice

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

Is it able to test output twice?
This is the code

```
<?php
public function testAutoTriggerOff()
{
    $user = array(
        'id'=>1,
        'name'=>'Andy',
        'logTime'=> time()
        );
    $this->elevent->turnOffAutoTrigger();
    $this->elevent->attach('Elevent\Test\Event\UserHasLoggedIn', new WelcomeUser);
    $event = $this->elevent->setEvent('Elevent\Test\Event\UserHasLoggedIn', $user);
    $this->expectOutputString('');
    $this->elevent->trigger($event);
    $this->expectOutputString('Welcome, Andy');
}
```

So, after the setEvent is called, I want to test that there is no output..
And, after the trigger is called, I want to test that the output is 'Welcome, Andy'
This test passed.
However, if I changed the first test output into something that should be false, such as

```
    $this->expectOutputString('this one should be false');
    $this->elevent->trigger($event);
    $this->expectOutputString('Welcome, Andy');
```

But, the test also passed. I expected it to fail, since I want to test the output twice.
Before the trigger, it should give no output.
After the trigger, the output should be 'Welcome, Andy'
How to test that way?

Comment: You are really testing two different things, so you should probably split it in two separate unit tests.

Comment: @jeroen No, I don't test different things.. I test if auto-trigger is really off.. If the auto-trigger is off, I need to call the trigger method to fire the listener.. If it's on, I don't need to call the trigger, it's auto-triggered since the event is set.. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `expectOutputString` evaluates the content echoed during the test. So if you call it twice you're overwriting the first expectation with the second.

If you think about it, the output is unique, you can't have 2 distinct outputs for a single test.

So @jeroen's comment was right. You need a test for checking that the output is void before triggering the event and another for checking the output after the event's triggered.

Looks like your class is echoing content directly. That will make it less testable. If you're using MVC pattern you usually only have one `echo` for sending the response content to the browser.

Comment: Not echoing content, but trigger the listeners.. The 'echo' in the listener is just for a test..